# Plotly boxplot: groupby option?

Tags: python, boxplot, plotly

I have two boolean variables and I try to create a boxplot with groups. Each group should represent one of the variables and it should contain two boxplots, one for TRUE and one for FALSE. Instead I am getting two groups, one representing TRUE and one representing FALSE and for each group two boxplots corresponding to each variable as in the attached graph:

[image: boxplot]

I understand that groups are derived from the xaxis. But how can I make plotly think that the variable names are the groups? The code I used for the output :

```
trace3= Box(
 y=raw_matrix.TPS,
 x=raw_matrix.noClassGc,
 name='noClassGc',
 marker=Marker(
 color='#3F5D7D'
))

trace4= Box(
 y=raw_matrix.TPS,
 x=raw_matrix.aggresiveOpts,
 name='aggresiveOpts',
 marker=Marker(
 color='#0099FF'
 ))

data = Data([trace3, trace4])
layout = Layout(
 yaxis=YAxis(
 title='confidence',
 zeroline=False),
 boxmode='group',
 boxgroupgap=0.5
 )


fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = ploteczki.plot(fig, filename='Performance by categoricals parameters')
```

Comment: here are some relevant examples

Answer (score 0):

You need to rearrange your data arrays so that the two `Box` traces have `'x'` coordinates of `'noClassGc'` and `'aggresiveOpts'`.

This [IPython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/etpinard/plotly-misc-nbs/blob/master/box-plot-groups.ipynb) shows you how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to represent each group by its boolean boxplots, you can assign each trace to different x-axes.  Here is an example:

```
trace0 = Box(
    y=raw_matrix_TPS,
    x=raw_matrix_noClassGc,
    name='noClassGc',
    marker=Marker(
        color='#3F5D7D'
    )
)
trace1 = Box(
    y=raw_matrix_TPS,
    x=raw_matrix_aggresiveOpts,
    name='aggresiveOpts',
    xaxis='x2',
    marker=Marker(
        color='#0099FF'
    )
)
data = Data([trace0, trace1])
layout = Layout(
    xaxis = XAxis(
        domain=[0, 0.55],
    ),
    xaxis2 = XAxis(
         domain=[0.55, 1],
    ),
    yaxis = YAxis(
         title='confidence',
         zeroline=False
    ),
    boxmode='group',
    boxgroupgap=0.5
)
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='Performance by categoricals parameters')
```

Here is [the link to the plot](https://plot.ly/~neda/5121/noclassgc-vs-aggresiveopts.png)

To learn more, you can checkout [Plotly Python reference](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#Box)