# How to group items on plotly boxplot

Tags: plotly, boxplot

I’ve reviewed the boxplot documentation and the workaround for supplying precomputing statistics for boxplots (https://plot.ly/~chris/18051/#code). Yet I still cannot achieve the following. Does anyone know how to achieve this grouping and coloring of boxes on a single plot?

[image: Box plots in groups.]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://plot.ly/python/box-plots/ under "Grouped Box Plots".

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x = ['day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1',
 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2']

trace0 = go.Box(
y=[0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3],
x=x,
name='kale',
marker=dict(
    color='#3D9970'
    )
)
```

As you can see, the length of the list containing the x-values used to groupby later on matches the length of the list of of y-values. The first 6 correspond to day 1 the other to day 2.

further explanation can be found here:
[Plotly boxplot: groupby option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987330/plotly-boxplot-groupby-option)

In short, you have to create/compile the x values of the boxplot according to the desired outcome. A simple groupby/hue option like in seaborn is missing unfortunately.